# Unable to boot even from usb drive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

## Problem description

After shutting down my computer last night and starting it again this morning, I have for no apparent reason lost the ability to boot into either of the installed OS (Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.10, using Grub). The system has two disks installed, with the boot partition located on the SSD.

- When Starting the system I get the grub error "unknown filesystem"
  and grub enters rescue mode.
- If I insert a bootable usb drive with any operating system on it (I
  tried different usb drives, different usb ports on my computer and
  different operating systems) I get the messing "*missing operating
  system*" or so for a second and then grub loads, displaying the normal
  boot menu (selection of my windows and ubuntu partitions).
- Selecting either of them results in a blinking underscore being
  displayed, followed by a black screen, followed by [image]

## Goal

At this point I simply want to be able to boot from a usb drive and setup the system anew. Since critical data is backed up, there's no considerations for data loss. I simply want to reinstall the os and get my computer functional again.

## Attempted solutions

- I have disconnected the SSD and tried booting from a usb drive, which is then listed as the only bootable partition. This causes an error saying "*Missing operating system. Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press key*". This is again the case with many usb drives, ports and os.
- As another post on SU suggested I created a stick with grub on it in order to boot into the existing os from there. This has failed as it simply ends up restarting the computer.
- I have installed a working version of windows including MBR on the SSD using a different computer. While being able to boot that on the other computer the problem persists on the original hardware - "no operating system found"

Comment: Try to boot into the BIOS and to reset it.

Comment: The BIOS of my mainboard (Z77 Pro3) offerend an option to "Reset to UEFI defaults", resetting the configuration in the setup menu. Doing this sadly did not affect any of the approaches I described

Comment: @deemel BIOS & UEFI are not the same thing, it's one or the either - you have UEFI. Sounds like you enabled CSM [Legacy] Mode in the UEFI firmware, which should always remain disabled _(CSM Mode's sole purpose was to support distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017)_. If you installed the OSes with CSM [Legacy] Mode enabled, it's recommended to configure Windows and Ubuntu for EFI boot. Once CSM Mode is set to what it was at OS install and Windows is still failing to boot, you'll need to use a boot fixer application in Linux, as Windows' `BootRec` will destroy GRUB boot.

Comment: I have disabled legacy mode in the usb section of the 'advanced options' of the uefi setup - now no usb devices (including my keyboard) are recognized. As far as I know there is some option to reset the uefi settings, I will consult the manual of my mainboard. I fear I have made things severely worse...

Comment: @deemel It's not a USB setting, but a boot setting. Your issue is quite simple: if the OSes were installed with CSM mode disabled _(generally the default of UEFI firmware)_,  the Windows BCD store simply needs to be rebuilt _(quite easy if not using GRUB via `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`, however doing so with GRUB will write over GRUB boot)_, so this needs to be fixed via a Linux boot fixer for Windows when using GRUB. Generally, the Windows error screen you're seeing displays with MBR boot, not EFI boot, so the CSM Mode status at the OS install needs to determined first.

Comment: I was unable to solve the problem with the mentioned software. I have updated my question with another attempted solution, which failed too. 
At this point I don't see how it can still be grub causing the problem, since the partition isn't even there anymore. It seems my mainboard is stuck in that problematic state and cannot recover even if I assign it to boot from a drive with a working os partition on it.I'm out of ideas

Comment: My first suspicion was an UEFI update that reset many settings back to defaults. Then you have to redo them. I have multiple settings I redo with every update. But if older system, you may not have an UEFI update available. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows issues, but report can show what issue is.

Comment: Im confused by your comment - your write to *not* use bootrepair for this , then describe steps that sound like they're done with bootrepair and link to it. So is the bootrepair live version fine for this or not ? Note that as I described I cannot start any live installer or a working install - this is a critical part of this issue. Live bootrepair and grub are the only that started so far

Comment: So it fails to find any system on any device, no matter what the system or the device is? Doesn't sound like a Windows problem then.